# How to stop malicious automatic iFrame Form Input from other site?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe

So there's a guy putting this code on his site:

```
<iframe name="frame" src="" frameborder="0"  width="1" height="1" allowfullscreen style="width:1;height:1;"></iframe>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="http://mysite.com/vote.php" target="frame">
  <input type="hidden" name="vote" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1337" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.forms.form.submit();
</script>
```

With this little piece of code he's tricking all my users into voting for a post (1337) in his favor.

How can I stop this? Any ideas?

I've tried the following (.htaccess) but it doesn't stop it:

```
# DISABLE IFRAME
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: You can probably fix it programmatically by checking the http referer your voting script is passed, and either discounting the votes.

Comment: @andrewsi there must be a cleaner way to solve this.

Comment: This is a [CSRF attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), the defences for which are [well-documented](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (see also: [coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)). Most web frameworks will have either native or plugin CSRF filters available.

Comment: @Quentin why isn't a http referrer check not sufficient?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann - a referer check is a quick and easy fix. It's also spoofable - if your guy is serious enough, it's trivial to work around. It will stop casual attacks, but you'll need proper code to stop someone more determined.

Comment: @JonasKaufmann — Because there are lots of circumstances when a browser won't send a referer (notably when coming off an HTTPS page).

Comment: @Quentin Well as long as my site doesn't use HTTPS I can simply kill all requests without a http referrer?

Comment: @JonasKaufmann — No, the header is optional. Some people disable it for privacy reasons. Some people get stuck being a proxy that filters it out.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Also, have you ensured that the HTTP header is being sent? Do note that the `X-Frame-Options` header is handled by the browser itself; therefore, it's not the other website doing anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming two things here:

1. You've got [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) installed and enabled;
2. You've placed your `Header` entries inside of a [`<IfModule mod_headers.c>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule) (or some variant thereof).

---

Whether my assumptions are correct or not, let's troubleshoot this issue:

1. **Make sure** that the actual header is being sent to the browser - you don't state anywhere in your question that you've tested this;
2. Try this additional header: `Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"`;
3. Remove the `<IfModule ...>` section, to see if Apache fails (or gives a warning) informing that the module isn't loaded;
4. You **do not** want to use `Header append ...` since that will *append* your desired value (to any possibly existing entry), and who knows how browsers will interpret that;
5. Maybe even try this:

   ```
   Header unset X-Frame-Options DENY
   Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
   ```

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to add a timely changing verification key to the real form and check that key when you process new entries.

Together with checking the http referrer this is pretty much bulletproof.

Simple solution:
Another great option is to simply check cookies. Set a cookie on the form page and check it on the submit page.

Good luck

Comment: If the verification key changes with time, then it can be scraped by the attacking site. It needs to change with the user.

Comment: The referer won't be sent under a lot of circumstances, such as when the attacker hosts their attack page on HTTPS. That isn't very helpful.

Comment: Cookies are no good for this. The attacker just has to make the user visit the page that sets the cookie before making them visit the form submission page.